# Prevent Keypress-events ( f.e. enter-key)

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm looking for stop keyboard events from ui-grid . For example: ui-grid navigates to the next row  by pressing the enter-key, here i need to prevent this action. Even using a cellTemplate which implements an ng-keypress-listener, I can't stop ui-grid to switch to the next row by hitting the enter-key.

Does anyone know how prevent ui-grid or switch off the keyboards events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the default functionality by overwriting their services/directives.

I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mlry2DCItK4aC1imUlWe?p=preview) for your case.

Copy the whole service containing the keyListener for cellNavigation and remove the `ENTER`-watcher.

```
getDirection: function (evt) {
      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.LEFT ||
        (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.TAB && evt.shiftKey)) {
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.LEFT;
      }
      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.RIGHT ||
        evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.TAB) {
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.RIGHT;
      }

      /*
      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.UP ||
        (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.ENTER && evt.shiftKey) ) {
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.UP;
      }
      */

      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.PG_UP){
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.PG_UP;
      }

      /*
      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.DOWN ||
        evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.ENTER && !(evt.ctrlKey || evt.altKey)) {
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.DOWN;
      }
      */

      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.PG_DOWN){
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.PG_DOWN;
      }

      return null;
},
```

The `direction.UP` and `direction.DOWN` checks are commented out but everything else works as expected. I appended the service at the bottom of the Plunkr app.js.

Comment: any idea on how to send the event to a controller? I want to perform some action on enter.

Comment: You can use broadcast. See new [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lDYcTW8RxqMfxQFYtm2K?p=preview) and press DOWN after selecting a cell. Its in lines 280 and 53.

Answer (score 4):

It works like charm, thanks a lot :)

I use now a decorator service to overwrite the method getDirection from ui-grid.

FYI. Here is the code:

```
angular
.module('app')
.config(function($provide){
  $provide.decorator('uiGridCellNavService', function ($delegate, uiGridConstants, uiGridCellNavConstants) {
    var getDirection = $delegate.getDirection;
    $delegate.getDirection = function (evt) {
      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.LEFT ||
        (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.TAB && evt.shiftKey)) {
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.LEFT;
      }
      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.RIGHT ||
        evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.TAB) {
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.RIGHT;
      }

      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.UP ||
        (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.ENTER && evt.shiftKey) ) {
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.UP;
      }

      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.PG_UP){
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.PG_UP;
      }
      // delete listener for key ENTER
      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.DOWN) {
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.DOWN;
      }
      // original code
      /*if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.DOWN ||
        evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.ENTER) {
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.DOWN;
      }*/

      if (evt.keyCode === uiGridConstants.keymap.PG_DOWN){
        return uiGridCellNavConstants.direction.PG_DOWN;
      }

      return null;
    };
    return $delegate;
  })
```

Comment: If you were able to solve your problem, mark the question as answered please.